# Two grids on the thumbnail to move on issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to create two grids with thumbnails and to be able to move thumbnails from one grid to another.
But there is a problem.

Look at the sample

http://jsfiddle.net/4hBWv/

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith:'.sortable'
    });
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

```
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sortable">
            <div class="ui-state-default">1</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">2</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">3</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">4</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">5</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">6</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">7</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">8</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">9</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">10</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">11</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">12</div>
    </td>
    <td class="sortable">
            <div class="ui-state-default">1</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">2</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">3</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">4</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">5</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">6</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">7</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">8</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">9</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">10</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">11</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default">12</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

If you try to move the thumbnails you will see an unpleasant blinking effect.

Please tell me why this is happening.

Comment: The problem mostly seems to stem from the fact that your sort container is a `td`. Multiple `div`s in another `div` do not have this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak3h7/

Comment: td that the reason is because the three columns consists of, because the height of the column to be the same.
And move between different grid rather than move from one grid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the jQueryUI code handling of sorting and `margin`.  If you change the CSS to have `margin: 0px 0px 0px 0` the problem goes away.

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XynWR/

Probably should be submitted to the UI folks as a bug.

Comment: @user1920486 - feel free to adjust the CSS to suit your needs :)